# convert date into format 2019-05-31T12:08:04Z momentjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

How to convert date into format `2019-05-31T12:08:04Z` using momentjs? And which format it is?

Comment: You can use `new Date().toISOString()`. If you are using moment, moment().toDate().toISOString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]');
```

Or

```
moment().format(moment.ISO_8601());
```

The second way you'll have the timezone

Answer (score 0):

This is the iso format, [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

As pindev said in comment you can do : `moment().toDate().toISOString()`

Comment: It's created string `2019-05-30T21:00:00.000Z`
Do you know how to format it into `2019-05-30T21:00:00Z`?

Comment: @fetchenko both are ISO format. The milliseconds (final `.000`) are optional.

Comment: Do you know how to remove them to get only 2 digits for seconds value?